# JQuery: adding more elements to an existing matched set using .add()

Tags: jquery, selector, addition

There may be a simple answer to this question, but for the life of me, I don't understand why the following two methods of using $.add() give me a different result set.

```
var toBeSorted;

if (contextEl.hasClass("lv"))
    toBeSorted = $(".lv", contextEl).add(contextEl);
else
    toBeSorted = $(".lv", contextEl);
```

versus

```
var toBeSorted = $(".lv", contextEl); 

if (contextEl.hasClass("lv"))
    toBeSorted.add(contextEl);
```

When the IF statement is true, I always get one more element in the top code segment than in the bottom code segment (namely *contextEl* is in the result set - which is exactly what I want).  I don't understand why the bottom method's way of calling *toBeSorted.add(contextEl)* doesn't do the trick?

Any pointers or advice is much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to write the resulting object after `.add()` back to `toBeSorted` as you do in the first code block.

```
toBeSorted = toBeSorted.add(contextEl);
```

Comment: oh man!!! of course!  thank you!  I knew it was something simple.  I forgot that it's not actually collecting into/modifying the original variable.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `andSelf` in this case which add the previous set of elements on the stack to the current set.

```
var toBeSorted = contextEl.find(".lv"); 

if (contextEl.hasClass("lv"))
    toBeSorted.andSelf();
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a nicer solution too (I think you meant $.andSelf().  I'll use your way as it looks more elegant, but as tandu pointed out, it needs to be like the following:

`toBeSorted = toBeSorted.andSelf();`

Comment: @JoJoeDad - Yes, I meant andSelf, it was typo. Thanks for letting me know.